# Error during compiling the string a[5 ] array in c++

Tags: c++

i want to know how can i store multiple characters in a array in c++, i just did like this but compiler made an error during compiling 
i declared it like below

```
char a[5]={"st","nd","rd","th","th"};
```

But couldn't made ,

is it ok or not .... i found errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int value=1;
int ivalue;
int sum=0;
int average;
int x,y;
int max=INT_MIN;
int min=INT_MAX;
int count=0;
int maxPos=1;
int minPos=1;
string A[5]={"st","nd","rd","th","th"};


cout << "Enter loop limit : "; cin >> value ;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

for( x=0;x<=value-1;x++){
    for (x=0;x<=A[5];x++)
        cout << "Enter "<<x+1<<A[0]<<" value : "; cin >> ivalue;
        sum=sum+ivalue;
        count++;

  if (ivalue>max)
 {
  max=ivalue;
maxPos = count;
 }
 if (ivalue<min)
{
min=ivalue;
minPos = count;
 }

}

   cout<<endl;
   cout<<endl;

   cout << "Sum of entered values = " <<sum <<endl;
   cout << "Average  value = "<< sum/value<<endl;
   cout << "Minimum value = " << min << endl;
   cout << "Minimum value entered at index :" << minPos << endl;
    cout << "Maximum value = " << max<< endl;
     cout << "Maximum  value entered at index : " << maxPos<< endl;

  }
```

Comment: Character array takes only one character. use char a[5]={"s","d","r","t","h"}; or look for the @zack answer

Comment: `for (x=0;x<=A[5]` is a mistake (in multiple ways). Pay attention to compiler messages. This code has a large number of mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to store are strings and not characters.

> `char` is one character. `string` is zero or more characters. They are different datatypes.

You can do -

`string list[] = {"st","nd","rd","th","th"};`

Answer (score 0):

This `char a[5]`, is an array of five characters of type `char[5]`.

This `"st"` is a string literal of type  `const char[2]`.

Thus, you're trying to aggregate initialize `a` which is an array of 5 `char`s with 5 string literals which are of type `const char[2]`.

Consequently, the compiler is rightfully complaining that it cannot assign to each one of the elements of the array, that are of type `char`, to its respective string literal in the aggregation list, which is of type `const char[2]`. That is, roughly it's telling you that you cannot do this:

```
char b = "st";
```

However, you can do this:

```
char const *b = "st";
```

This is due to the fact that in C/C++ arrays can decay to pointers that point to the first element of the array.

Accordingly, you can change to the following:

```
char const *a[5] = {"st","nd","rd","th","th"};
```

That is, change your type of your array `a` to hold pointers to `const char`. This way every pointer in your array will point to the first element of its respective string literal in the aggregation list.

Comment: Maybe consider adding some explanations because the OP doesn't seem experienced to understand this alone.

Comment: @Mayerz hope now is satisfactory.